# c# Checked List Box dynamically binding from database and get the selected value

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2, checkedlistbox

hi i am looking for a solution i given my code below
when i added static item on the checked list box and selecting a item i am getting the item on the message box is like "Some listbox value"
But with the same code i am binding checked list box from the database value i am getting the message box value as `System.Data.DataRowView`
what should i do to get the solution anybody help me

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (object s1 in ChGetQtnNumber.CheckedItems)
        {
            string getdetailofQtn = s1.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(getdetailofQtn);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You get datarowview.You have to get your column value. Youcan do this by

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        foreach (object s1 in ChGetQtnNumber.CheckedItems)
        {
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)s1;
            string getdetailofQtn = drv["ColumnName"].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(getdetailofQtn);
        }
}
```

Comment: form where i can get the ["ColumnName"]

Comment: it is database column name. You can copy that value. Or you can use drv[0] it will also give what you want i think.

Comment: i have 2 checked listbox 1 i have two item "Helo" and "Hai" when i select helo , select * from table where qtn='helo' helos value will bind on 2nd checked listbox when i select hai, hai's value will be bnd on 2nd checked listbox, then  i want select from 2nd listbox item vaue to the string here i am just selecting a item i think there is no need to read from database

Comment: Yes. By the way please check as answer for others use